# Is extern "C" required also for linking global variables used in Cpp file to the one defined in a cfile?

Tags: c++, c, extern

Is extern "C" required also for linking global variables used in Cpp file to the one defined in a c file?

It is used for linking function from C++ file which is referenced in C file because of the name mangling of function names in C++ files. Does the C compiler also changes the name of variables??

Answer (score 5):

> Is `extern "C"` required also for linking global variables used in Cpp file to the one defined in a c file?

Portably, yes.

You might find that leaving out `extern "C"` works for your compiler (for example, GCC, which doesn't mangle C++ variable names in the global namespace), but that's not something you can rely on for all compilers.

> Does the C compiler also changes the name of variables??

It depends on the compiler (specifically, on the ABI it uses). The language standards don't specify how language-level names map to linker symbols, so different compilers can use different name-mangling schemes.

Comment: While gcc does not mangle C++ variable names in the global namespace, I've encountered that Visual C++ *does*.

Comment: @BrunoDeFraine : I was getting linking error infact in gcc.

Answer (score 1):

It is not required for variables. Extern "C" is required for functions because in C++ the functions can be defined multiple times for different number and type of parameters. Each function name includes parameters in encoded form. But the variables cannot be redefined and the names are identical (compatible) in C and C++.

Comment: Citation needed. I can't find anything in the specification of language linkage to say that C and C++ linkage are the same for variables.

Comment: Very simple - make project with .c and .cpp file, define `int my_int` in both of them, assign value in .c and read it in .cpp. The only difference can be underline char `_` in .c which can be enabled/disabled from compiler options/IDE.

Comment: That may be true for your compiler. Where in the standard does it specify that this is the case for all conforming compilers?